# How to use the current file name as the the output name in the File Output Node and without the frame number at the end?

Tags: node-editor

Two questions:

1. How to use the name of the currently opened blendfile **automatically** in the *File Path* field of the *File Output Node* without entering it manually?
2. How to remove the frame number which is automatically appended at the end of output file (especially for static images)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AFAIK the answer to both is **No**.

The frame number padding zeros can be configured by adding `#` to the filename:

From the [wiki page on CLI rendering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/workflows/command_line.html):

> ```
>  -o or --render-output <path>
>      Set the render path and file name.
>      Use // at the start of the path to
>          render relative to the blend file.
>      The # characters are replaced by the frame number, and used to define zero padding.
>          ani_##_test.png becomes ani_01_test.png
>          test-######.png becomes test-000001.png
>          When the filename does not contain #, The suffix #### is added to the filename
>      The frame number will be added at the end of the filename.
>          eg: blender -b foobar.blend -o //render_ -F PNG -x 1 -a
>          //render_ becomes //render_####, writing frames as //render_0001.png//
> ```

This works in the GUI too:

[image]

So the above becomes `render01.png`, `render02.png` etc.
A single `#` = no padding. (i.e. `render1.png`)

However, I don't think there is a way to completely remove the frame number from the file name through blender, though it's really not hard to remove it later.

---

As for the blendfile name in the *Base Path*:
You could write a python script to set the *Base Path* of all *File Output* nodes to the blendfile name:

```
import bpy
import os

# Get file name:
filename = bpy.path.basename(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath)

# Remove .blend extension:
filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

# set the base path for all file output nodes to filename:
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    for node in scene.node_tree.nodes:
        if node.type == 'OUTPUT_FILE':
            node.base_path = "//" + filename
```

Comment: We can also put the `#` placeholder within the *File Output* node's file path. e.g. specifying `Image#.png` will create `Image1.png`, `Image2.png`, etc.

Comment: For anyone that stumbles on this old post as I did. The wiki link noted above for CLI rendering has been changed to: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/workflows/command_line.html

Comment: @crazycourier Thanks, I've edited the new link in.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried to see if it works the same with other render formats, but when I render videos from blender, I prevent it putting frame numbers in the render by specifying the full filename, with extension.

For example, if I specify //output in the Output field in the GUI, it will generate a file that starts with output in the project directory but will have the start and end frames in the name.  If, however, I specify //output.avi in the Output field then that's exactly the name I'll get.

Unfortunately, I too have not found a way to have it just use the blend file name.

Answer (score 1):

I think [p2or/blender-loom: image sequence rendering, encoding and playback](https://github.com/p2or/blender-loom#file-path-variables) can do what you want.